# Cutting a polygon into 2 or 3 smaller, rationally-scaled copies of itself?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, rational-numbers, tiling

I've noticed that many 2D geometric figures can be tiled using four smaller copies of themselves. For example, here's how to subdivide a rectangle, equilateral triangle, and right triomino into four smaller copies:

[image: a rectangle subdivided into four similar rectangles, an equilateral triangle subdivided into four smaller equilateral triangles, and a right triomino subdivided into four smaller right triominoes]

Each smaller figure here is scaled down by a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ in width and height, dropping its area by a factor of four, which is why there are four smaller figures in each.

You can also tile some 2D figures with nine smaller copies, each $\frac{1}{3}$ of the original size, or sixteen smaller copies, each $\frac{1}{4}$ of the original size, as shown here:

[image: a rectangle subdivided into nine self-similar smaller copies; an equilateral triangle subdivided into nine-self-similar copies; a right triomino subdivided into sixteen self-similar copies]

By mixing and matching sizes, we can get other numbers of figures in the subdivisions. For example, here's a $2 \times 1$ rectangle subdivided into five rectangles of the same aspect ratio, an equilateral triangle subdivided into eleven equilateral triangles, and a right triomino tiled by thirty-eight right triominoes:

[image: a <span class=]$2 \times 1$ rectangle subdivided into five rectangles of the same aspect ratio, an equilateral triangle subdivided into eleven equilateral triangles, and a right triomino tiled by thirty-eight right triominoes" />

I've been looking for a shape that can tile itself with exactly two or three smaller copies. I know this is possible if we allow the smaller copies to be scaled down by arbitrary amounts, but I haven't been able to find a shape that can tile itself with two or three copies of itself when those smaller copies are scaled down by rational amounts (e.g. by a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{3}{5}$).

### My Question

My question is the following:

> ***Is there a 2D polygon that can be tiled with two or three smaller copies of itself such that each smaller copy's dimensions are a rational multiple of the original size?***

If we drop the restriction about the smaller figures having their dimensions scaled by a rational multiple, we can do this pretty easily. For example, a rectangle of aspect ratio $\sqrt{2} : 1$ can tile itself with two smaller copies, and a rectangle of aspect ratio $\sqrt{3} : 1$ can tile itself with three smaller copies:

[image: a <span class=]$\sqrt{2}:1$ rectangle cut into two self-similar copies, and a $\sqrt{3}:1$ rectangle cut into three self-similar copies" />

However, in these figures, the two smaller copies are scaled down by a factor of $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$, respectively, which aren't rational numbers.

If we move away from classical polygons and allow for fractals, then we can do this with a Sierpinski triangle, which can be tiled by three smaller copies of itself. However, it's a fractal, not a polygon.

### What I've Tried

If we scale down a 2D figure by a factor of $\frac{a}{b}$, then its area drops to a $\frac{a^2}{b^2}$ fraction of its original area. This led me to explore writing $1$ as a sum of squares of rational numbers, such as $1 = \frac{4}{9} + \frac{4}{9} + \frac{1}{9}$ or $1 = \frac{9}{25} + \frac{16}{25}$. This gives several possible values for how to scale down the smaller copies of the polygon, but doesn't give a strategy for choosing the shapes of the reduced-size polygon to get the smaller pieces to perfectly tile it.

I've looked into other problems like [squaring the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_square) and other similar tiling problems. However, none of the figures I've found so far allow for a figure to be tiled with two or three copies of itself.

I've also tried drawing a bunch of figures on paper and seeing what happens, but none of them are panning out.

Is this even possible in the first place?

Thanks!

Comment: You might be interested in https://erich-friedman.github.io/mathmagic/0605.html

Comment: Could be worth having a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rep-tile

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a 345 triangle, and draw the altitude from the hypotenuse to the opposite corner.
To get three pieces, cut one of the two pieces in the same way.

Comment: Same should work for any right triangle with all sides integral.

Answer (score 0):

A trapezoid with side lengths in the ratio of 1:1:2:sqrt(2) is an irreptile. It can be cut into three similar trapezoids, two small and one large.

Consider the trapezoid bounded by 0<x<2 and 0<y<4-x. It can be cut into three similar trapezoids bounded by:

1. 0<x<1 and 0<y<2-x;
2. 1<x<2 and 0<y<x; and
3. 2-x<y<4-x, 0<x, and y>x.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I've added an image of this trapezoid. Note though that the dimensions of the large internal trapezoid are not a rational multiple of the original trapezoid. It covers half the area so the ratio of the side lengths is $\sqrt2:1$

Answer (score 0):

If all three pieces are the same size, then it is impossible, without invoking fractals, for the smaller pieces to have dimensions that are a rational multiple of the original object's size.

In order for the area of the new shape to be $n$ times the area of the original, and still be similar, we must multiply the linear dimensions by $\sqrt{n}$.  Since $1/3$ is not a perfect square, $\sqrt{1/3}$ is not a rational number.  In order to avoid this we can use fractals, as you saw with the Sierpinski triangle, which allows us to use the fractal dimension instead of the "real-space" dimension.